# Facebook Open Graph Actions don't work unless user does re-login

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

We just got our Open graph action approved and deployed it, but it is not working for old users who are already logged in.

It works perfectly for new users, or for users who have logged in again. But for Users who leave their browsers logged-in, or have never logged out of our app, it does not post the open graph actions.

Does anyone know what to do in such cases? Do I have to invalidate all users, and force them to re-authenticate?

Comment: Have their access_token already expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to new New Facebook SDK.